# Qt: How to use Qt's Smartpointers

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, smart-pointers

I have experience in "old-fashioned" C++ programming (i.e. I care myself about pointers and memory management). I do want to make use of modern concepts though.

Since my application makes heavy use of Qt, I'd like to use Qt's smartpointers. I am however somewhat confused about smartpointers in general, and their use in Qt.

1.) As far as I understand, if I derive from `QObject`, I should better stick to Qt's object tree and ownership model and forget about smartpointers. Correct?

2.) In C++ I can get by with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. What are the equivalent smart pointers in Qt?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
QList<MyObject *> * foobar(MyOtherObject *ptr) {

   // do some stuff with MyOtherObject

   QList<MyObject* > ls = new QList<MyObject*>();
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {    
       MyObject* mi = new MyObject();
       ...
       ls.insert(mi);
   }
   return ls;
}

int main() {

   MyOtherObject* foo = new MyOtherObject();
   QList<MyObject*> *bar = foobar(foo);
  // do stuff
  // and don't care about cleaning up?!
}
```

3.) How to translate the above snippet into a version using smartpointers?

4.) In particular: Should I change function signature into using smartpointers? It seems to create quite complex type signatures (return type and passed arguments). Also what if some "legacy" function calls another function - is it better to write function signatures with raw pointers, and use smartpointers only "inside" functions?

5.) What smartpointer should replace `ls` in the function `foobar`? What is the pointer type that should be used for `mi`, i.e. the objects stored in the `QList`?

Comment: If you use Qt, you are more or less forced to use Qt's parent system to manage memory (=delete) of `QObject`s. I suggest you follow that pattern. For any other objects allocated on heap (that do not derive from `QObject`), use standard smart pointers - `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers in your container at all? Why not just `QList<MyObject>`?

Comment: Why not use `QList<MyObject>`? 1.) Just for the sake of an example and 2.) these could be complex objects created on the heap for whatever reason, i.e. size, or dynamically created elsewhere.

Comment: Qt is pretty old; it introduced many classes before there were standard `std::` equivalents. That doesn't mean they are better. That said, `QString` is probably slightly easier to use.

Comment: For the sake of the example: Don't return a pointer to QList<>, return the QList<> itself. 1) The compiler should be able to perfor RVO or std::move 2) Quite a few classes (especially containers, including QList) use [Implicit Sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html) i.e. copying the object will result in a shallow copy (which is very cheap, both memory and peformance wise), that will only detach (i.e. deep copy)  if you do something to change it (perform non-const operations on it).

Comment: ndbd : you should accept an answer, it has received enough attention and good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty much forced to use `Qt` idiom of owning raw pointers for GUI objects, as `QWidget` derived types will assume ownership of child elements.

Elsewhere, you should as much as possible avoid using *any* type of pointer. Most of the time you can pass a reference. If you need polymorphic ownership, then use `std::unique_ptr`. In *very rare* cicrcumstances, you have multiple independent lifetimes that need ownership of a shared resource, for which you use `std::shared_ptr`.

The Qt collection classes also interact badly with modern C++ constructs, e.g.

```
extern QList<Foo> getFoos();

for (const Foo & foo : getFoos()) 
{ /*foo is a dangling reference here*/ }

for (const Foo & foo : std::as_const(getFoos()))
{ /*This is safe*/ }
```

Your snippet would be

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> foobar(MyOtherObject & obj) {

   // do some stuff with MyOtherObject

   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>> ls;
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   { 
       ls.emplace_back(std::make_unique<MyObject>());
       ...
   }
   return ls;
}

int main() {

   MyOtherObject foo = MyOtherObject;
   auto bar = foobar(foo);
  // do stuff
  // destructors do the cleanup automatically
}
```

Comment: `QObject` ownership is a catch-all - it can be preempted. It's there when you need it, but you don't have to use it at all by preempting it.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. As far as I understand, if I derive from QObject, I should better stick to Qt's object tree and ownership model and forget about
>      smartpointers. Correct?

Better to say "it depends". First, you should know what [thread affinity in Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/thread-basics.html) is. Good example - [`QThread worker`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).

`QObject` uses parent-child memory management, so if the parent is destroyed, then all its children will be destroyed too.  In the "Qt way", it is enough to manage only root object lifetime. It is very easy, when you create `QObject`-based classes on heap (for example, with `new` operator). But there are some exceptions:

- You should be careful with objects [that are created on the stack](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).
- Classes with parent-child relations should belong to the same thread. You may use [`QObject::moveToThread()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) method to control thread affinity. So if instances of related objects should belong to different threads, they may not have parent-child relations.

  There is a pattern to auto-delete objects that belong to different threads. For example, if we should delete `p2` when `p1` is destroyed:

  ```
  QThread t;
  t.start();
  QObject *p1 = new MyClass1{};
  p1->moveToThread( &t );
  p1->doSomeWork();
  QObject *p2 = new MyClass2{};
  QObject::connect( p1, &QObject::destroyed, p2, &QObject::deleteLater ); // here
  ```

  Object `p2` will be destroyed when you delete `p1`.

  We've employed a useful method above: [`QObject::deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater). It schedules object deletion asap. It may be used in several cases:
- You need to delete an object from within a slot or during emitting of a signal. You should not delete such objects directly, because it may cause problems. Example: self-destroying button (somewhere in `MyClass`):

  ```
  auto btn = new QPushButton{/*...*/};
  QObject::connect( btn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyClass::onClicked );

  void MyClass::onClicked()
  {
      auto p = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>( sender() );
      // delete p; // Will cause error, because it is forbidden to delete objects during signal/slot calls
      p->deleteLater(); // OK, deletion will occurs after exit from the slot and will be correct
  }
  ```

For working with QObject-based pointer there is a [`QPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html) helper. It will not automatically delete an object, but it will be valid all the time. It will contain a reference to an object or a `nullptr`. When object is removed, all its `QPointer` instances will be nulled automatically. Example:

```
class Foo : public QObject { /* ... */ };

class Bar
{
public:
    void setup( Foo * foo )
    {
        p = foo;
    }

    void use()
    {
        if ( p )
        {
            p->doSomething(); // Safe
        }
    }

private:
    QPointer<Foo> p;
};
// ...
Foo * foo = new Foo{};
Bar bar;
bar.setup( foo );
delete foo; // or not delete
bar.use();  // OK, it's safe
```

Note, that `QPointer` uses the `QObject::destroyed()`signal for managing internal reference, so using it to keep a large amount of objects may cause performance issues (only on mass creation/destruction). Performance with accessing to this pointers is same as with raw pointers.

> 2. In C++ I can get by with `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. What are the equivalent smart pointers in Qt?

Yes, there are [`QSharedPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html) and [`QScopedPointer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html) that work in similar way. Some benefits for using these pointers include [custom deleters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscopedpointer.html#details), like `QScopedPointerDeleter`, `QScopedPointerArrayDeleter`, `QScopedPointerPodDeleter`, `QScopedPointerDeleteLater`.

Also you may use something like this, for QObject-based classes, if you need postponed deletion:

```
QSharedPointer<MyObject>(new MyObject, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Attention: you should not use this smart pointer with direct setting of parent objects, because destructor will be called twice.

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
QScopedPointer<MyClass> p;

public:
Foo()
    : p{ new MyClass(this) } // NO!!! Use new MyClass() without specifying parent
// Object lifetime is tracked by QScopedPointer
{}
};
```

If you have a list of raw pointers, you may use helpers like [`qDeleteAll()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-1) for cleanup. Example:

```
QList<MyObject *> list;
//...
qDeleteAll( list );
list.clear();
```

> 3.
>
> 4.
>
> 5.

It depends on your design and C++ code style. Personal approach, from my experience:

1. Use parent-child only for `QWidget`-based classes.
2. Use shared pointers only when you can't control an object lifetime
3. In all other cases - use unique pointers
4. To share something between two classes - use [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).
5. In case of complex logic - use smart pointers. But double-check
   for loops (use weak pointers in most cases)

Feel free to ask in comments for any clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, modern C++ allows you to use values, and Qt supports that. Thus, the default should be to use `QObject`s as if they were non-movable, non-copyable values. Your snippet, in fact, requires no explicit memory management at all. And this does not clash at all with the fact that the objects have a parent.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <list>

using MyObject = QObject;
using MyOtherObject = QObject;

std::list<MyObject> makeObjects(MyOtherObject *other, QObject *parent = {}) {
  std::list<MyObject> list;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    #if __cplusplus >= 201703L // C++17 allows more concise code
    auto &obj = list.emplace_back(parent);
    #else
    auto &obj = (list.emplace_back(parent), list.back());
    #endif
    //...
  }
  return list;
}

int main() {
  MyOtherObject other;
  auto objects = makeObjects(&other, &other);
  //...
  objects.erase(objects.begin()); // the container manages lifetimes
  //
}
```

C++ has strict object destruction order, and `objects` is guaranteed to be destroyed before `other`. Thus, by the time `other.~QObject()` runs, there are no `MyObject` children, and thus there's no issue with double-deletion.

In general, here are the viable approaches to storing `QObject` collections, with their requirements:

1. `std::array` - all elements of same type, fixed size, cannot be returned
2. `std::list` - all elements of same type, doesn't have a `RandomAccessIterator`, container owns the objects
3. `std::deque` - all elements of same type, has `RandomAccessIterator` but doesn't allow `erase` since your objects are not `MoveAssignable` (but of course can be cleared/destroyed), container owns the objects
4. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>` - elements of any type i.e. it is a polymorphic container, container owns the objects
5. `std::vector<QObject*>` or `QObjectList` - non-owning, non-tracking container. Qt code is full of `QObjectList = QList<QObject*>`.
6. `QObject` (sic!) - elements of any `QObject` type, container optionally owns the objects, container tracks the object lifetime, the element pointer can be used to remove the object from the container; only one container can hold a given object, uses a bare vector to store the objects and thus additions/removals of children are `O(N)`.

When storing the objects themselves, and not their collections, with object lifetime being the same as the containing scope, it's easiest to keep them as values. For example:

```
class ButtonGrid : public QWidget {
  static constexpr int const N = 3;
  QGridLayout m_gridLayout{this};
  QLabel m_label;
  std::array<QPushButton, N*N> m_buttons;
public:
  ButtonGrid(QWidget *parent = {}) : QWidget{parent} {
     int r = 0, c = 0;
     m_gridLayout.addWidget(&m_label, r, c, 1, N);
     r ++;
     for (auto &b : m_buttons) {
        m_gridLayout.addWidget(&b, r, c);
        c ++;
        if (c == N)
           c = 0, r ++;
     }
  }
};
```

Now, to answer your questions:

1. *Should I better stick to Qt's object tree and ownership model?* There's no choice in that matter: that model is there and it can't be disabled. But it's designed as a catch-all and you can preempt it. `QObject` ownership model only ensures that children don't outlive the parent. It prevents resource leaks. You're free to end the childrens' lives before the parent dies. You're also free to have parentless objects.
2. *What are the equivalent smart pointers in Qt?* It doesn't matter. You're writing C++ - use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`. There's no benefit to using Qt's equivalents since Qt 5.7: from that version onwards, Qt requires C++11 support in the compiler, and thus those pointers must be supported.
3. *How to translate the above snippet into a version using smart pointers?* There's no need to. Keep objects by value. Perhaps you need to have a different snippet that would actually require the use of smart pointers.
4. *Should I change function signature into using smart pointers?* No. You haven't motivated any smart pointer use.
5. N/A

Answer (score 2):

> 1.) As far as I understand, if I derive from QObject, I should better stick to Qt's object tree and ownership model and forget about
>   smartpointers. Correct?

Yes. When using `QObjects`, I would recommend to rely on it's parent - child model to manage memory. It works well and you can't avoid it altogether, so use that.

> 2.) In C++ I can get by with std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr. What are the equivalent smart pointers in Qt?

There is `QSharedPointer` and `QScopedPointer`, which is somewhat similar to `unique_ptr`, but doesn't support move semantics. IMHO there is no reason to use these nowadays, just use the smart pointers provided by standard library (to manage lifetime of objects that do not derive from `QObject`).

> 4.) In particular: Should I change function signature into using smartpointers? It seems to create quite complex type signatures
>   (return type and passed arguments). Also what if some "legacy"
>   function calls another function - is it better to write function
>   signatures with raw pointers, and use smartpointers only "inside"
>   functions?

Generally - use smart pointers only to manage memory = use them only when there is an ownership relation. If you just pass an instance to a function that works with it but doesn't take ownership, pass just a plain old pointer.

Concerning your example, it's a bit hard to say without context. Both `ls` and `mi` could be a `unique_ptr`. Better, you could just allocate `ls` on stack. And even better, avoid using `QList` and use `std::vector` or something like that.